# Material Ui and react-router onClick event delay in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-router

I have a react application with @material-ui/core v.1.2.1 and react-router 3.0.2 (currently I can't update it). When I click a button that handles navigation it takes 2 seconds to work.

[image]

I've added  to my index.html to avoid the onClick event delay.

Material ui's documentation talks about  [how to deal with third-party routing libraries](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library) but my buttons needs some logic before navigation so I can't use this solution. Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but I am aware of this package that's supposed to fix tap delay from onClick on mobile with React: https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin

Answer (score 0):

[FastClick for React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fastclick) fixed it for me.